# how to resolve "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/velocity/context/Context"

Tags: web-services, exception, cxf

I'm a new learner of apache cxf. in the first program i implement, i encoutered the following **exception**( this is what my console display):
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/velocity/context/Context
The java code source i run is 
    package com.ttdev;

import org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava;

public class CodeGenerator {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("debug");
    WSDLToJava.main(new String[] {
            "-server",
            "-d", "src/main/java",
            "src/main/resources/Service.wsdl" });
            System.out.println("Done!");
}
```

}
so how can i resolve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need Apache Velocity on your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Pom->DependencyHierarchy -> Filter "velocity"
In which package it is found , Probably it was not loaded properly.

In mycase it was C:\Users\MyUser.m2\repository\org\apache\velocity

Delete that and run "mvn clean package -DskipTests" from console, it will download all necessary packages.